# Why does the lxc container binds more than the configured ip?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, lxc

I set up several ubuntu LXC containers on my ubuntu server. 
They all have a unique IP configured. 
As they start up, some of them do bind more than the defined IP address. 
For example container A has 10.0.3.123 and binds additionally 10.0.3.127. 

Thank you for any help. 

LXC version: 1.0.6-0ubuntu0.1

The configuration of the container CA:
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/ubuntu.common.conf
lxc.arch = x86_64
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/CA/rootfs
lxc.utsname = CA
lxc.console = /var/lib/lxc/CA/console
lxc.mount = /var/lib/lxc/CAfstab
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.ipv4 = 10.0.3.123/24
lxc.start.auto = 1

The output of # lxc-ls -f:
NAME                  STATE    IPV4                    IPV6  AUTOSTART  
----------------------------------------------------------------------
CA              RUNNING  10.0.3.123, 10.0.3.127  -     YES

Comment: Edit your post and paste : - /usr/share/lxc/config/ubuntu.common.conf (host) - /etc/network/interfaces (lxc container)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container is most likely assigning 10.0.3.127 from the built-in dhcp server.  Disable dhcp inside the container or disable the assignment in the config.

Comment: found the crendentials for the portal, now i can say thank you :)

Comment: @wolxXx, glad I could help.  Please mark this as resolved then.

Comment: /etc/lxc/dnsmasq.conf:

dhcp-host=CA,10.0.3.10
dhcp-host=CB,10.0.3.11
dhcp-host=CB,10.0.3.12
etc